# Dynamically creating different objects from a dataset

Tags: c#, reflection, datatable, activator

I am attempting to use a DataTable to create and populate a group of objects. I was hoping to create one function that would know what type of object to create based on the `type` passed into the function. Then using either the object returned by `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` or Reflection, populate the objects fields with the data in the dataset. Here is my function:

```
private object DataTableToObject(DataTable table, Type type)
{
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    //we are only concerned with the first row here

    var row = table.Rows[0];

    /* do something here to populate the fields of MyObject */
}
```

I was hoping to call this function like this...

```
var dataTable1 = DataTableToObject(dataSet.Tables[dataSet.Tables.IndexOf("MyCustomObject")]);
MyCustomObject custObj = DataTableToObject(dataTable1, typeof(MyCustomObject));
```

Edit: What is the best way to populate the fields in the object at runtime? Do I need to use reflection to get the field names, then using the field names, populate the object somehow?

Solution!

```
private T DataTableToObject<T>(DataTable table)
{
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

    //we are only concerned with the first row because in our datasets, we should only have one row per table
    var row = table.Rows[0];

    foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        var propInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(col.ColumnName);
        if (propInfo == null) continue;

        object colValue;
        if(propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
           colValue = Guid.Parse(row[col.ColumnName].ToString());
        else 
           colValue = Convert.ChangeType(row[col.ColumnName], propInfo.PropertyType);

        propInfo.SetValue(obj, colValue, null);
     }
     return (T) obj;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect from us? Write it for you? You are on the right track. Just go on...

Comment: Edited. Sorry I was so focused on explaining the question I didnt actually ask it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make the method generic:

```
private T DataTableToObject<T>(DataTable table)
```

and then change it up a little:

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
```

and at the end of the method remember to cast it:

```
return (T)obj;
```

and now, when you call it, it will look like this:

```
MyCustomObject custObj = DataTableToObject<MyCustomObject>(dataTable1);
```

And now how to populate the fields, I would do something like this:

```
foreach (var col in table.Columns)
{
    var propInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(col.Name);
    if (propInfo == null) { continue; }

    propInfo.SetValue(obj, row[col.Name], null);
}
```

Comment: `var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));` seems to work better than the alternative. How can I access the fields of `obj`?

Comment: @gwin003, see my edit for the process to get at the properties.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am giving it a try now. Had to adjust your `foreach` loop a bit. I will edit if this works.

Comment: @gwin003, fantastic! I'm guessing you couldn't use `var` but may have had to explicitly type to `DataColumn`?

Comment: Yes, and `col.Name` had to be `col.ColumnName`. I am getting a `ArgumentException` now, because its trying to put a `String` into an `Int32` field. I'm working on it...

Comment: @gwin003, got it! And yeah, I was making an assumption that the types you were returning actually matched the types of the properties you were setting. If they don't it will take a bit more massaging but this at least got you 90%+

Comment: Yep, I will get this part figured out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @gwin003, not a problem! I'm glad I could be of assistance!